# Keras: fit_generator get much lower accuracy then the evaluate_generator just one line above?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am following the [blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) for transfer learning:

```
##First I compute the saved the bottleneck features and build a new model and train it with the bottleneck features: 
input_layer = Input(shape=base_model.output_shape[1:])
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(input_layer)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu',name='fc_new_1')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu',name='fc_new_2')(x)
x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax',name='logit_new')(x)
Add_layers = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=x,name='Add_layers')

##Then I put this new model at the end of pretrained models: 
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=
(img_shape[0],img_shape[1],3))
x = base_model.output
predictions = Add_layers(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=
['accuracy'])

##Then, I evaluate the model : 
score = model.evaluate_generator(train_generator, nb_train_samples // 
batch_size_finetuning)
print('The evaluation of the entire model before fine tuning : ')
print(score)
score = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, nb_validation_samples 
// batch_size_evaluation)
print('The evaluation of the entire model before fine tuning : ')
print(score)
```

And get training loss and accuracy : `[0.015362062912073827, 1.0]`
validation loss and accuracy : `[0.89740632474422455, 0.75]`

```
##Just one line below it, I trained the new model: 
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch= nb_train_samples // batch_size_finetuning,
                epochs=finetuning_epoch,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                validation_steps=nb_validation_samples //batch_size_evaluation,
                callbacks=[checkpointer_finetuning, 
 history_finetuning,TB_finetuning,
lrate_finetuning,Eartly_Stopping_finetuning]);
```

Then the output is :

```
31/31 [==============================] - 35s - loss: 3.4004 - acc: 0.3297 - val_loss: 0.9591 - val_acc: 0.7083
```

Weird thing is: This problem only happens if I use `Resnet50` and `InceptionV3` but not with `vgg16`. I am pretty sure that changing the pretrained model is the only difference. I understand that the dropout might make it different but it should not be this large and `vgg16` has no obvious problem at all.

Another weird thing is: If I change every layer to be `.trainable = False` and compile, the validation accuracy will still decrease dramatically. I even checked the weights of every layer and if `.trainable = False` weights will not change and `.trainable = True` weights will change.

Any help is appreciated!!! THANKS!!!

Comment: any one had similar problem?